# Grouped Collection View list not displaying, possible Binding error

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

I just began working with the MVVM layout and I cannot seem to display anything in my `collectionView` List. I believe it's my binding, unfortunately I don't really understand how I am supposed to bind a grouped list + the ViewModel. I read to bind to the path no the source, but I'm pretty sure I am doing this incorrectly. I have checked to see if I am even getting shares to load and I am, they're just not displaying.

**Model -- Share**

```
 [JsonProperty("iSpottedID")]
 public int ID { get; set; }

 [JsonProperty("sShoppingList")]
 [MaxLength(255)]
 public string ShoppingName { get; set; }

 [JsonProperty("dtInfoUpdate")]
 [MaxLength(20)]
 public string CreateDate { get; set; }

 [JsonProperty("iProductID")]
 public int ProductID { get; set; }

 [Indexed]
 [JsonProperty("sLocation")]
 [MaxLength(255)]
public string LocationName { get; set; }

 [JsonProperty("tvCardJson")]
 public string JsonString { get; set; }
```

**ViewModel -- SharesViewModel**
public class SharesViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
#region Properties

```
    private int _id;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id;  }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _id, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ID));
        }
    }

    private string _longName;
    public string LongName
    {
        get { return _longName; }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _longName, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LongName));
        }
    }

    private string _date;
    public string CreateDate
    {
        get{ return _date;}
        set
        {

            SetValue(ref _date, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CreateDate));
        }
    }

    private int _prodID;
    public int ProductID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _prodID, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProductID));
        }
    }

    private string _json;
    public string JsonString
    {
        get { return _json; }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _json, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(JsonString));
        }
    }

   
    private string _location;
    public string LocationName
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _location, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LocationName));
        }
    }

    //ADD-ONS
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JsonString))
            {
                var jsonDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(JsonString);
                if (jsonDict.ContainsKey("address"))
                    if (jsonDict["address"] != "")
                        return jsonDict["address"];
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private ImageSource _imageLink;
    public ImageSource ImageLink
    {
        get
        {
            if(ProductID != 0)
            {
               ...
                 return ImageSource.FromUri(link);
            }
            return null; 
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public SharesViewModel(){}
    public SharesViewModel(Share share)
    {
        ID = share.ID;
        ProductID = share.ProductID;
        JsonString = share.JsonString;
        CreateDate = share.CreateDate;
        LocationName = share.LocationName;
    }
```

**List View Model -- SharesListViewlModel**

```
  public class SharesListViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        
private SharesViewModel _selectedShare;
private bool _isDataLoaded;
//grouped list
public ObservableCollection<LocationSpotGroups<string, SharesViewModel>> Shares { get;  set; }
...
public ICommand OpenMoreSharesCommand { get; private set; }
public ICommand LoadDataCommand { get; private set; }
public SharesListViewModel(Position NW , Position SE)
   {
     _nw = NW;
     _se = SE;

     LoadDataCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadData());
     OpenMoreSharesCommand = new Command<SharesViewModel>(async (share) => await OpenMoreShares(share));
      public ObservableCollection<SharesViewModel> sList { get;  set; }
      = new ObservableCollection<SharesViewModel>();
   }

  private async Task LoadData()
        {
            if (_isDataLoaded)
                return;

          
            var list = await _connection.GetAllRegionShares(_nw, _se);
            foreach (var spot in list)
            {
               sList.Add(new SharesViewModel(spot));
            }

            var sorted = from item in sList
                         orderby item.LocationName
                         group item by item.LocationName into itemGroup
                         select new LocationSpotGroups<string, SharesViewModel>(itemGroup.Key, itemGroup);

            Shares = new ObservableCollection<LocationSpotGroups<string, SharesViewModel>>(sorted);
        }
```

**LocationSpotGroups**

```
 public class LocationSpotGroups<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        
        public K GroupKey { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<T> GroupedItem { get; set; }
      

        public LocationSpotGroups(K key, IEnumerable<T> shares) 
        {
            GroupKey = key;
            GroupedItem = shares;

            foreach (var item in shares)
            {
                this.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

**SharesPage XAML**

```
  <CollectionView x:Name="CollectionList"
                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Shares}"
                           IsGrouped="True">
               <!--HEADER-->
               <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Padding="5"
                                    BackgroundColor="#f7f7fb">

                           <Label x:Name="labelname"
                                  Text="{Binding GroupKey}"
                                  HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                  VerticalOptions="Center"
                                  TextColor="gray" />
                       </StackLayout>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

  <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

               <!--BODY-->
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="5" Margin="8">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ImageButton Source="{Binding ImageLink}"
                               WidthRequest="150"
                               HeightRequest="150"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                               CornerRadius="15"
                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="0"/>
                        
                        <Label Text="{Binding ShoppingName}"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="0"/>

                         <Label Text="More"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>

                        <Label Text="{Binding CreateDate}"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               Grid.Column="0"/>
                                         </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

**SharesPage CS**

```
 public SharesPage( Position NW, Position SE )
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new SharesListViewModel(NW, SE);
        }


        public SharesListViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return BindingContext as SharesListViewModel; }
            set { BindingContext = value; }
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            ViewModel.LoadDataCommand.Execute(null);
            base.OnAppearing();

        }
```

Comment: you possibly need to raise a PropertyChanged event in the setter of `Shares`

Comment: @Jason what about my bindings? Are they done correctly? I don't get an error either when running my code.

Comment: they look ok at a glance.  But you are assigning your VM to the BindingContext **before** `Shares` has been created, so you need to fire a `PropertyChanged` when that happens so the UI knows to update.   If you continue to have problems, I would suggest starting with a simple non-grouped CV with one Label.  Get that working first, then add a more complex template.  Get that working, then modify it to work with grouped data.  Incremental steps

Comment: A simple way to check your binding is to add some dummy data to `Shares` like [what did to AnimalGroup here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping#example) in your viewmodel constructor, and have a go.

Comment: Thanks @Shaw, the issue is Shares is not being set. I did some test data and it all works. Now I am just working on getting the propertyChanged to be raised afterwards to set the data.

Comment: How is it going?

Comment: Yes @AdrainZhu-MSFT Thank you. I ended up loading my items in the constructor. it's not a lot of data and it seems to work fine after some more testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the data in the constructor works if the data is not a lot, which is wasn't in my case. Everything loads perfectly.